# JIRA : order to create JIRA stuff inside a project

Tags: jira

I only have an english documentation to administrate and create a big JIRA project. And it's a little big difficult for me, because current language in software is french.

If I understood JIRA philosophy, I have to do the following from step 1 to 6 .... haven't I?

1. Create project
2. Create an issue type and the issue type scheme
3. Create a screen, then a screen scheme and at last an issue type screen scheme
4. Create customized fields
5. Create news states, then a workflow, with steps and transitions
6. At last, create permissions and roe projects

I will appreciate your help.

Thanks a lot,

Christophe

Comment: There is no need to follow specific steps. As soon as you create the project, you can start. However, if you want specific configurations of your project, you will need to dive into the manual or get help from one of the many companies that offer consultancy for Atlassian products in your country.

Answer (score 1):

To start using Jira, first [create Users](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Managing+Users) and a [Project](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Defining+a+Project). then, you can customize jira to better fits your needs:

- [Creating a Custom Workflow](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Creating+a+Custom+Workflow)
- [add customized fields](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Adding+a+Custom+Field)
- [create your own issue types](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Defining+%27Issue+Type%27+Field+Values)
- [create your own Screens](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Defining+a+Screen)
- [Add Notifications](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Creating+a+Notification+Scheme)
- add advanced option, for example [create issue from email](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Creating+Issues+and+Comments+from+Email)
- [add plugins](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/)

This is only a partial list, since practically every aspect of Jira can be customized and extended. for more information, check [Jira's online help](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/JIRA+Documentation)